# Chrome dev tools doesn't show the event listener added via extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I added an onclick event listener to an element from the page DOM from a extension content script.

When I trigger the element event listener I can see that it logs to the console, perfect. But I wanted to know why the event doesn't appear on the dev tools element event listeners tab. Or does it show somewhere else?
Tried this on chrome and firefox.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

content.js

```
const div = document.getElementById("id")

div.addEventListener("click", function () {
   console.log("extension click")
})
```

Chrome dev tools: in this case no click event here
[image]

Comment: Do you have the element selected? I don't remember off hand whether that's necessary.

Comment: Yes, on the element tab I have the element selected (highlighted in blue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented in devtools, see and star https://crbug.com/1190426.

Meanwhile you can switch the console context to your extension and use `getEventListeners($0)` either as a live expression or directly in console.

[image]

[image]

The live expression result can be right-clicked and saved to a variable for further inspection.

Comment: Wow that's nice to know! Is this on purpose because the extensions live in "different world" ? Or just not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It lives in it's own world, so to speak. When I am debugging a chrome extension, I usually right click on it: [image: Inspect Popup]

Then, I click on Inspect Popup and I can see the console, breakpoints, HTML, CSS, and Javascript. In addition, I have access to Event Listeners: [image: Event Listeners]

Comment: In this case I injected code to the main DOM. Didn't mean the popup.