# Why am I not able to view event listeners added by a Chrome extension in DevTools' Event Listeners tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, addeventlistener

I am using Chrome 101 in Windows 10 and have a Chrome extension installed which does an addEventListener("mouseover"..) on every element on the page. I am unable to view these events in the Event Listeners tab in DevTools. This seems to be a bug according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66717347/chrome-dev-tools-doesnt-show-the-event-listener-added-via-extension-content-scr). The page shows a workaround. However, the workaround doesn't show the event listener for me.

I switched the console to the extension's context. For several selected different elements and doing a getEventListeners($0), I always get an empty object as shown. I am not sure if this option got broken or what.

Are there any other ways to display these types of event listeners? The mouseover does work on the page and if I put a breakpoint on this event, the debugger stops in the extension's code (along with code from the page).

[image]

Comment: It means the extension adds the listener on a different element. Probably on `window` or `document`.

Comment: No it's adding it to every element. I also removed the mouseover listener in devtools for the document and the elements' mouseover listeners still work. The mouseover listener is removed for the document and it doesn't show up anymore in the events list.

Comment: Also ran this script to show the number of mouseover listeners and there are over 200 of them after running the extension. Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
.reduce(function(pre, dom){
var evtObj = getEventListeners(dom)
Object.keys(evtObj).forEach(function (evt) {
if (typeof pre[evt] === 'undefined') {
pre[evt] = 0
}
pre[evt] += evtObj[evt].length
})
return pre
}, {})

Comment: I've checked the source code of the extension and it doesn't add the listeners on all elements. It adds on document.body.

Comment: Looks like it does add it to the body. The ForEach loop threw me off. Although after selecting the body tag, getEventListeners($0) didn't show the mouseover event.

Comment: Devtools resets the context after you select the node, so you need to reselect the context again.